# Where to write HDFS data such they can be read with HIVE

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hadoop, hive

Given I write HDFS with apache spark like this:

```
var df = spark.readStream
  .format("kafka")
  //.option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "kafka1:19092")
  .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "localhost:29092")
  .option("subscribe", "my_event")
  .option("includeHeaders", "true")
  .option("startingOffsets", "earliest")
  .load()

df = df.selectExpr("CAST(topic AS STRING)", "CAST(partition AS STRING)", "CAST(offset AS STRING)", "CAST(value AS STRING)")
val emp_schema = new StructType()
  .add("id", StringType, true)
  .add("timestamp", TimestampType, true)

df = df.select(
  functions.col("topic"),
  functions.col("partition"),
  functions.col("offset"),
  functions.from_json(functions.col("value"), emp_schema).alias("data"))
df = df.select("topic", "partition", "offset", "data.*")

val query = df.writeStream
  .format("csv")
  .option("path", "hdfs://172.30.0.5:8020/test")
  .option("checkpointLocation", "checkpoint")
  .start()

query.awaitTermination()
```

Here `hdfs://172.30.0.5:8020` is the namenode. It seems this spark program is writing data successfully to the nameode.

How can I query this data from hive? Do I have to write the data into a special folder that hive can see it? Must I define a database for this folder? And how is this done? Where is the location of `test` then on the file-system?

Answer (score 1):

> Where is the location of test then on the file-system?

It's at `/test`

Note: if you properly configure `fs.defaultFS`  in the core-site.xml, then you don't need to specify the full namenode address.

> Do I have to write the data into a special folder that hive can see it?

You can, and that would be easiest, but the docs cover both options of "managed" (a dedicated HDFS location) and "external" (any other directory, with other restrictions) Hive tables

https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-data-sources-hive-tables.html

> How can I query this data from hive?

See above link.

---

FWIW, Confluent has a Kafka Connector that can write data to HDFS and create Hive tables

Comment: What do you mean by not specifying the namenode address? Where do I not need to specify it?

Comment: Instead of `option("path", "hdfs://ip:port/path"`, you can just do `option("path", "/path"`

Comment: The HDFS is actually on another container, not on the spark node itself

Comment: That doesn't matter. The `fs.defaultFS` will use the defined filesystem if a URI scheme is not specified